# html5 number type 'min' and 'max' implementation in symfony2

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

Please is there a way of implementing HTML5 number type 'min' and 'max' in symfony2?

I have try this:

```
->add('min_age', 'integer', array ('min' => '18', 'max' => '90' ))
```

and getting error "The options "max", "min" do not exist".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As these are attributes of the field element, do the following:

```
->add('min_age', 'integer', array('attr' => array(
    'min' => '18',
    'max' => '90',
)));
```

It will render the form element with `min` and `max` attributes.